# Import/export named ranges and their values to and from workbook to .csv

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a .csv with two columns: colA has named ranges and colB has the values.

Now I need to import the values from the .csv and assign them to the named ranges in the workbook present in multiple sheets. Also I need to export the same in the same manner. i.e. A workbook has named ranges and obviously some associated values.

Is there a way to export in the same format so that I can use it to import them later?

For import I modified the code provided as an answer below but still unsuccessful:

```
Option Explicit
Sub impdata()
'This is to import data from csv to xlsm

Dim MyCSV As Workbook
Dim filename As String
Dim curfilename As String
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Workbook

curfilename = ThisWorkbook.Name
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

Set y = Workbooks(curfilename)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Set MyRange = MyCSV.Worksheets("Import").Range("B2:B7") 

    x = 1
    For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
        Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value)).Cells(x) = MyCell.Value     'Method "Range_of_object" Global failed
        x = x + 1
    Next MyCell

MyCSV.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Need to get this right - column A in your CSV has the names of the named ranges in Excel and you want to take the values in column B of the CSV and put it into that named range within Excel?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes correct

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Please have a look I modified it but still getting error ;(

Comment: I'm guessing your CSV sheet isn't called `NamesToRanges`.  It's usually the CSV filename - actually, scratch that.... a CSV has 1 sheet so use `MyCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B7")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes Sorry for that silly mistake but now I am getting another error on 'Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value)).Cells(x) = MyCell.Value     'Method "Range_of_object" Global failed'

Comment: I've rewritten the code (see bottom of my post) - will hopefully work as intended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read the values in from the CSV - providing the Named Range and values in the CSV are the same size and a single column.

In my example code the CSV has two different named ranges - A1:A3 hold 'NamedRangeA' and B1:B3 hold the values, A4:A6 hold 'NamedRangeB' and B4:B6 hold the values.  There are two named ranges in the Excel workbook, both 3 rows by 1 column.

```
Sub ReadIn()

    Dim MyCSV As Workbook
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\crladmin.ADMINNOT\Desktop\New Folder\NamesToRanges.CSV")
    Set MyRange = MyCSV.Worksheets("NamesToRanges").Range("A1:B6")

    x = 1
    For Each MyCell In MyRange.Columns(2).Cells
        Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value)).Cells(x) = MyCell.Value
        x = x + 1
    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Will hopefully point you in the right direction - just have to figure out the reading out to a CSV now.

**Edit:**
Have rewritten the code:

It will now ask you for the location of your CSV, it will use the first (and only) sheet in the CSV.
Have also got rid of the *X* variable as realised it wouldn't work if your named ranges weren't.  Will now put the next value in the next empty cell in your named range.

```
Sub impdata()

    Dim MyCSV As Workbook
    Dim MyCSVPath As String
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim MyNextCell As Range
    Dim MyNamedRange As Range

    MyCSVPath = GetFile

    If MyCSVPath <> "" Then
        Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open(MyCSVPath)
        Set MyRange = MyCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B7") 'Ensure B2:B7 is where your values are.

        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells

            'Get a reference to the named range.
            Set MyNamedRange = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value))

            'Find the next empty cell in the named range.
            Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(MyNamedRange.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            'If the next empty cell is above the named range, then set
            'it to the first cell in the range.
            If MyNextCell.Row < MyNamedRange.Cells(1).Row Then
                Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(1)
            End If

            'Place the value in the range.
            MyNextCell = MyCell.Value

        Next MyCell
    End If

    MyCSV.Close False

End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetFile
' Date      : 13/11/2013
' Purpose   : Returns the full file path of the selected file
' To Use    : vFile = GetFile()
'           : vFile = GetFile("S:\Bartrup-CookD\Customer Services Phone Reports")
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Comma Separate Values", "*.CSV", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for me every named range is of one cell dimension only and there are toal 374 named ranges. I will try to adjust it to suit it for me

Comment: Looking at the code - you could probably adjust `MyRange` to look at `B1:B6` and remove the `Columns(2)` argument in the `For...Each` loop.

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/702irlzwa50mpbx/Import.csv?dl=0) is the csv file if you want to have a look

Comment: Good stuff.  You can update this row `MyCSVPath = GetFile` so it goes straight to the correct folder - `MyCSVPath = GetFile("<Your folder path>")`