# How to import/export multicell namedrange in .csv format

Tags: vba, excel, csv, importerror

I wanted to know is there any way to work around this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282646/import-export-named-ranges-and-their-values-to-and-from-workbook-to-csv) so that I can import and export named ranges and their values from a workbook to and via `.csv` file format.

I can successfully import or export the named ranges of single cell. But I get error while exporting the multicell named ranges as they are arrays.

> Code for exporting the named ranges to csv is this

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportCSV()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1 As String
Dim i As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Export")

With ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Activate


ws.Range("A1").Select
Selection.ListNames


 FinalRow = ws.Range("B9000").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 1 To FinalRow
    Cells(i, "B") = Replace(Cells(i, "B"), "$", "")
 Next i

     Dim fileSaveName As Variant

     fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                                        fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv")
     If fileSaveName <> False Then
        'Code to save the file
      ws.Copy

       With ActiveWorkbook
       .SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
       .Close False

       End With
     End If
ws.Cells.Clear

End With
Worksheets("Preferences").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Data Exported Successfully at " & vbNewLine & fileSaveName, vbInformation


End Sub
```

> Code for importing named ranges and their values is this

```
Option Explicit
Sub impdata()

    Dim MyCSV As Workbook
    Dim MyCSVPath As String
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim MyNextCell As Range
    Dim MyNamedRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FinalRow As Long



    MyCSVPath = GetFile

    If MyCSVPath <> "" Then
        Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open(MyCSVPath)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ws = Sheets(1)
        FinalRow = ws.Range("B90000").End(xlUp).Row
        Set MyRange = MyCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("B1" & ":B" & FinalRow)



        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells

            'Get a reference to the named range.
            Set MyNamedRange = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value))

            'Find the next empty cell in the named range.
            Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(MyNamedRange.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            'If the next empty cell is above the named range, then set
            'it to the first cell in the range.
            If MyNextCell.Row < MyNamedRange.Cells(1).Row Then
                Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(1)
            End If

            'Place the value in the range.
            MyNextCell = MyCell.Value

        Next MyCell
    End If

    MyCSV.Close False
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetFile
' Date      : 23/10/2015
' Purpose   : Returns the full file path of the selected file
' To Use    : vFile = GetFile()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Comma Separate Values", "*.CSV", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What error do you get, and on which line?

Comment: @TimWilliams The error is with importing and exporting the multicell namedranges have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282646/import-export-named-ranges-and-their-values-to-and-from-workbook-to-csv) if you can please.

Comment: @RohanK : Rather than adding a link to your old question (that most people won't follow) you should include directly the detailed explanation so that helpers won't have to trail the information. ;) Your export code only seems to export your list of Named Ranges and not the data coming with it, what are the issues for this one? And the other? More pointers coming into an answer (not enough place here)

Comment: Your previous question doesn't provide any insight into *exactly* what your current problem is.  "But I get error" - *what error*, and on which lines?  What exactly is happening, and how is it different from what you want/expect to happen?

Comment: @TimWilliams What i expect to happen is simple - Just want to export the named ranges and their values from the workbook to a csv file. And then use the same exported csv file to import the named ranges and values from the csv to the main workbook. Make sense?

Comment: @TimWilliams The error is not on any line the error is while exporting the multicelled named ranges they return #VALUE! error get it ?

Answer (score 1):

### Export Code

You've put `With ws` and didn't really use it your code, it'd be safer and also much more practical to do so! ;)

Here is the new export code, it will keep a master file listing your Named Ranges with the value if there is only one cell or the file name (placed in the folder "Save_as_CSV", so that you can find it to re-import it) if there is multiple cells :

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportCSV()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    WsO As Worksheet, _
    Str1 As String, _
    i As Long, _
    ShName As String, _
    RgName As String, _
    FileName As String, _
    FileFullName As String, _
    RgO As Range, _
    FinalRow As Long, _
    FileSaveName As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Ws = Sheets("Export")
Set WsO = Sheets("OutPut")

With Ws
    .Range("A1").ListNames
    FinalRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "B"), ":") Then
            'NamedRange with Multiple cellS
            ShName = Replace(Replace(Split(.Cells(i, "B"), "!")(0), "=", ""), "'", "")
            RgName = Replace(Split(.Cells(i, "B"), "!")(1), "$", "")
            Set RgO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShName).Range(RgName)
            WsO.Cells.Clear
            WsO.Range("A1").Resize(RgO.Rows.Count, RgO.Columns.Count).Value = RgO.Value
            FileName = .Cells(i, "A") & ".csv"
            FileFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Save_as_CSV\" & FileName
            'Code to save the file
            WsO.Copy
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs FileName:=FileFullName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
                .Close False
            End With
            .Cells(i, "B") = FileName
        Else
            'NamedRange with only one cell
            .Cells(i, "B") = Replace(.Cells(i, "B"), "$", "")
        End If
    Next i

    FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv")
    If FileSaveName <> False Then
        'Code to save the file
        .Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:=FileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
    .Cells.Clear
End With

Worksheets("Preferences").Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Data Exported Successfully at " & vbNewLine & FileSaveName, vbInformation
End Sub
```

### Import Code

1. `MyNextCell = MyCell.Value` (I think `MyCell.Value` is the address of the named range) should be :

   ```
   MyNextCell.Resize(Range(MyCell.Value).Rows.Count, _
                       Range(MyCell.Value).Columns.Count).Value = _
          Sheets(Names(MyCell.Value).RefersToRange.Parent.Name).Range(MyCell.Value).Value
   ```
2. If you work with CSV, this might be better `Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open(MyCSVPath, Local:=True)` than `Set MyCSV = Workbooks.Open(MyCSVPath)`
3. If you want to add the data to what you already have (I tilted after that you must be trying only to update it), `Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(MyNamedRange.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` 
   (will start at the end of the named range and go up, then Offset, so it'll give you the second line of the named range) 
   should be :

   ```
   Set MyNextCell = MyNamedRange.Cells(MyNamedRange.Cells.Count).Offset(1)
   ```

Comment: I am really sorry but I am really not able to follow your answers. In Import code I have used ws at many instances. And in Export code I can't find where I have used MyNextCell = MyCell.Value anywhere in the code. 
Also if you look at the code for exporting it works fine for singlecell named ranges but fails for multicell named ranges. I just can't figure out to do that.

Comment: you can have a look at the whole file to test the macro they are all on the first sheet. [FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pghrtpfgy1kgbc5/BFF24bkup.xlsm?dl=0) .

Comment: `'Place the value in the range. MyNextCell = MyCell.Value` is directly taken from your export code, so take a better look! ;)
I'll put the curated import code into my answer.
**My main question for additional details is :**  In the B column of your file, you say that you have the NamedRange's data, but I guess you are saying that it is the NamedRange's address, because if it isn't you SURE CANNOT work with multicell NamedRange.

Comment: But the main problem is with the export code if it won't export the named ranges and values properly how can it import it ? You have placed the ExportCSv in the Import code of your answer. Also I tried the ExportCSV code from the answer above it still has #Value! error for multicell Named Ranges e.g "Buckets" is a mutlicell named ranges.

Comment: Ok, I finally got what you are trying to do... So the problem here, is **how do you want to display multiple cells into only one cell**?

Comment: Yes that's correct but not exactly. What I am trying to do is just copy the named ranges and their values and export to csv and I should be able to import the values from the exported csv file later. Understand ?

Comment: @RohanK : Yes, I now definitly got that part, but as you are trying to do this in a single file with **2 columns, you have to put multiple cells into only one for NamedRanges with multiple cells** so my question was how do you propose/want to do that? Because the whole issue is in that question

Comment: It doesn't matter how many columns it takes I just want to import and export the data successfully. The only question that I have is how can I import/export multicell namedranges because those are the ones causing the problem.

Comment: For me the best thing would be to have a complete list like you have now, referring to other CSV files for multiples cells ranges. Heavier but that would work fully...

Comment: Complete list of what ? Can you just direct me here I am ready to do the way you think it will work. Thank you. An example would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at what the new version of export does : If it is only one cell, take the value directly. If there is more than one cell, create a new CSV file to store the data and keep the NamedRange in the list that you generate so that you can reload it afterwards. If it seems ok to you, try to change the import part with the advice I gave and post it into your OP's edit and I'll try to take time to help you finish it properly! ;)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help, I tried but still unsuccessful with export the namedranges I get error. I think it's just not possible :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94052/discussion-between-rohan-k-and-r3uk).